# MSMQ - Send copies of messages received

Tags: msmq

Is there any way to configure an MSMQ queue to send copies of all messages it receives to another MSMQ queue? I have a memory leak on a production application that services a queue.  I have a test version (that hopefully fixes the memory leak) on a test server, that services a test queue.  I want to deluge the test version with the production stream of messages, to ensure that the memory leak has been fixed.  After I am done testing, I would like to shut off this "message forwarding"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on my application, I was faced with 2 solutions, the easiest one I would recommend you to do is to make a very simple application that Peeks every message in a Queue via a transaction, and send a copy of the Message object to another queue, and you're done, just Abort() the transaction, that way you can be sure it'll be restored and wait for the production app to process the messages.

The other alternative would be to have the Message Queue apps just send the messages to yet another message queue, that way you don't have to mess around with peeks in Production and you'll have full access to your own queue in a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

No. MSMQ is a protocol for delivering messages. You would need an application to read the delivered messages and send new copies to a different queue.

Comment: Nothing can be done with acknowledgements or anything of the like?

Comment: It's just like the physical postal service. Try asking the postman to send a copy of all your letters to another destination.